# How to automate south migrations in an install script

Tags: django, installation, data-migration, django-south

I have a Django project using South that includes an install script. What I'd like to do is have a couple of lines of code in that install script that take care of installing and syncing my database with my latest code so that new installations of the project can easily get their database set up.

I could run...

```
python manage.py migrate --fake 0010 appname1
python manage.py migrate --fake 0004 appname2
```

...but I can't put that into the install script because (1)I don't know the migration number in advance, and (2) I'd rather not have to keep the install script up to date with the app names.

What I need is something like:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake --allmigrations --allapps
```

Is there a trick for this?

Comment: Seconding @John's question, why are you using `--fake` for deployment? Anyway, regardless of that,  `migrate` or `migrate appname` will just run all unapplied migrations for all apps / specified app. Same thing with `--fake`

Comment: @Beres, see my response to @John, below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking you should not be using --fake during your deployment.  Fake means it doesn't actually run the migration and if your use case says you are always going to use --fake (because you're doing the migrations by hand) then why are you bothering to try to get them into your deployment script at all.

That said.  If you do intend to run the migrations with your deployment script, it's relatively trivial.  Simply run manage.py migrate.  No app names not migration numbers.  You could even do manage.py migrate --fake and it will fake migrate all migrations for all apps.  The real question if you do that though is why the heck you would bother.

Comment: This is for new installations, so I presume that running syncdb puts the latest models into the DB, negating the need for the migrations. After that point, yes, I do want to migrate, but if a new user is installing the software, and it comes with a dozen migrations, they shouldn't run them, right?

Comment: No actually they should (generally).  Let's say the new user checks out your repository.  As soon as they get it South is already installed and your apps are already under migration control so syncdb will do nothing with those apps and running the migrations (from 0001_initial) will in fact create the entire database

Comment: To add a little to why some apps will make exceptions to that rule.  Over time an app will develop potentially hundreds of migrations.  Sometimes these can take a long time to run or even have problems running from scratch due to ill defined dependencies.  Sometimes in these cases it's easier to have the new install instructions (or script) disable south and use syncdb, then enable south and --fake all the migrations.  This is the exception rather than the rule.

Comment: This clarifies. So South's syncdb will recognize that it's a new installation, will set up the schema that existed before South was used on the app, and then will migrate things forwards? I must have something broken about an early migration in that case.

Comment: On a "new" installation no schema will exist.  If schema already exists it isn't a new install and you will need to --fake migrations up to the point where the schema matches the migration.  If it's truly a new install south will create the full schema from scratch.  However one of the most common issue in that case is that you haven't actually tested creating the schema from scratch and haven't set dependencies correctly: http://south.aeracode.org/docs/dependencies.html?highlight=depends_on#dependencies

Comment: The convert_to_south docs even covers this.  http://south.aeracode.org/docs/convertinganapp.html#converting-other-installations-and-servers The convert_to_south utility creates a 0001 migrations that takes the schema from scratch up to the current schema.  All other currently existing copies of that schema will need to --fake the first migration while new installs will simply need to run the migration